# Connect to a remote Raspberry running RetroPie

Tags: retropie, vpn

I'm building a game station for a friend and a need a way in to the Raspberry from my home. It can be as simple as a remote FTP server but the ideal solution would be a VPN that gave me total control over the machine. I've found a lot of tutorials but none of them for what I actually need to achieve. Is there a (possibly) free and relatively easy solution to this?

Comment: This is a networking / Linux question that has nothing specific to do with Raspberry Pi.  You might do better searching https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: How about forwarding a port in his router to the Pi, and ssh-ing in?

Answer (score 0):

If you drag a blank file called 'ssh' with no extension onto the SD card you will be able to log into it via PuTTY (or terminal if on a mac), from here enter the command `vncserver :1`. This will start a vnc server and will display the ip address to enter in the vnc client (download from [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/)). You can then log in with the username (defaults are Username: 'pi', Password: 'raspberry'). If you sign up for an account online you can sign in with it using instructions [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/raspberry-pi.html) (go down to 'Establishing a cloud connection' and follow the instructions).

Now when you want to use it on a different network access it via the client while you are logged in!

Hope this helped!